# this.$set cant sort after

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

So have Vue adding an object to a list of objects but no matter what I do it doesn't seem to sort or append to the top of the list.

the set happens here

```
 watch: {
     sendBetData() {
        // Creates the object to be appended to the list 
        const latest = {
          bet_id: this.sendBetData.bet_id, 
          username: this.sendBetData.username, 
          bet: this.sendBetData.bet_amount,
          client_seed: this.sendBetData.client_seed.seed,
          created_at: this.sendBetData.created_at,
          high: this.sendBetData.high,
          multiplier: this.sendBetData.multiplier,
          profit: this.sendBetData.profit,
          result: this.sendBetData.result,
          roll: this.sendBetData.roll_number,
          server_seed: this.sendBetData.server_seed.seed_hash,
          threshold: this.sendBetData.threshold,
          user_id: this.sendBetData.user_id
          };
            this.$set(this.bets, latest.bet_id, latest)
        },

    },
```

then I have a computed function sorting

```
computed: {
      bets() {
        console.log('yep');
        return _.orderBy(this.bets, 'created_at')
      }
    },
```

But no matter what I try it always sets it to the bottom of the list on the view

Comment: You aren't using `Vue.set` properly. From the documentation, here is a proper example: `this.$set(this.someObject, 'b', 2)`, where `this.someObject` is the object which you want to set, `'b'` is the attribute you want to change on `this.someObject`, and 2 is the new value to be set

Comment: So that isnt the right way to append a new object to the group?? The way you putting it is that is the change a value within an object, is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array of objects, just push it:

```
this.bets.push(latest)
```

Also, your `orderBy` method should probably be `sortBy` given what you want to do:

```
return _.sortBy(this.bets, bet => bet.created_at)
```